# why it show Unregistered Android application message when login with gmail in android app?

Tags: android, permissions, gmail

In my Android application while login with gmail its showing me a dialog with a message Unregistered Android application with other permissions while I have set SCOPE only gmail but it is showing additional one in permission 'Unregistered Android application'.

Can any one suggest us please?

Comment: What Apis do you use, can you show some code, related to sign in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To use gmail sign in function, you must get an AppId from google play services APIs. Follow this link to get one: [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)